# Spring profiling using xml

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a spring application and need to pass in different implementations of a bean based on envt. 
My bean is defined this way:

```
 <bean id="com.myStep"
        class="com.myStep">
    <property name="onSuccess" ref="com.loadStep"/>
    <property name="onError" ref="com.dontLoadStep"/>
</bean>
```

I need to pass different implementation of loadStep,something like the following during prodction envt :

```
<bean id="com.loadStep"
            class="com.loadStep">
    <constructor-arg ref="com.remoteProvider"/>
</bean>
```

Something like this in dev envt:

```
<bean id="com.loadStep"
                class="com.loadStep">
        <constructor-arg ref="com.localProvider"/>
    </bean>
```

I have tried

```
<beans profile="prod">
<bean id="com.loadStep"
            class="com.loadStep">
    <constructor-arg ref="com.remoteProvider"/>
</bean>
```

and for dev:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="com.loadStep"
                class="com.loadStep">
        <constructor-arg ref="com.localProvider"/>
    </bean>
```

I **dont** have envt specific xml,so i am defining both the profiles in same xml. When i try this,i get an error as the same bean id is used for both dev and prod profiles.

Comment: what version of spring are you using

Comment: I am using spring 3